# Is there any way to implement autofill and autogenerate results feature in Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to do a document search application using Elastic search(NEST client).
I would like to know if there is way to do an auto fill feature using ES.

Something like "As in when i type some text in search text box, it start returning results based on that few text. Similar to google."

TIA

Comment: There are _many many_ different ways to do this and it may be much more complicated for some domains than others. I would recommend looking at completion suggesters to begin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html, as well as the nest example app - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/master

Comment: @RussCam thanks Russ. Will have a look at the links you have provided.